# Calculating 5 year rolling returns

Tags: python, pandas, finance, quandl, economics

I have the below code which has returns for U.S. stocks over the period Jan 1995 to Dec 2000. I wish to calculate the return for Jan 2001 using a 60-month rolling return in Python. As there is 5 years of returns, how is this possible?

I would like to calculate this for each stock over the time period Jan 2001 to Dec 2010. Any assistance would be awesome!

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Use Quandl to get adjusted close price
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'Enter Your Key'
stocks = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'WMT', 'GE', 'KO', 'F', 'JNJ', 'BA', 'XOM']
stockdata = quandl.get_table('WIKI/PRICES', ticker = stocks, paginate=True,
                    qopts = { 'columns': ['date', 'ticker', 'adj_close'] },
                    date = { 'gte': '1995-1-1', 'lte': '2000-12-31' })

# Setting date as index with columns of tickers and adjusted closing 
# price
data1 = stockdata.set_index('date')
table = data1.pivot(columns='ticker')
table.head()

# Daily and annual returns of the stocks
returns_daily = table.pct_change()
returns_daily.head()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.rolling()` to create the subset for the 60 month rolling return

```
returns_5year=table.rolling(250*6).pct_change()
```

And if you want yearly returns, use 'asfreq('BA')`

```
returns_yearly = table.asfreq('BA').pct_change()
```

Comment: How did you arrive on "250*6" ?

Are you assuming that data is present for 25 days in each month?

Comment: the 250 is a short hand to give a quick example, it all depends on how you arrange your data

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had a follow-up question about rolling(). From what I understand, rolling() returns even those windows which have periods less than (250*6). For example, it will return the first row too even though we don't have data for 60 months back.

Is there a way to make it return only those windows which have exactly (250*6) periods between them?